# Ternary operator and graph position specifier

Tags: graph, gnuplot, ternary-operator

### Is there any way to specify a yrange using the graph position specifier?

I want to plot a function inside a specific region of the canvas. I have absolute values for the xrange, but for the yrange I want it to go from, for example, `y>graph 0.7 and y<graph 0.8`, i.e, I want the y values of the function vary from 70% till 80% of the values of the actual yrange. More specifically, I want something like this:

```
plot (x<x_min || x>x_max) || (y<graph 0.7 || y>graph 0.8) ? 1/0 : the_function(x)
```

Well, I tried to do this, but it didn't work: gnuplot returns an error. I also searched for a solution, but had no success.

Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1/0` only works with data points. You can use the special data file `"+"` for this purpose, which in the end is the same as plotting a function, where gnuplot is sampling the function at discrete intervals:

```
set xrange [-2*pi:2*pi]
plot "+" u ($1):($1 > -pi && $1 < pi ? sin($1) : 1/0) w l
```

[image]

Comment: @Larara Yeah, it's pretty handy :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly use `graph` for coordinates used inside plot. This works only for labels, objects and arrows. Gnuplot evaluates the function on the whole x-range and then determines the automatic y-range. So you cannot have access to an automatically computed y-range at the time the function is evaluated.

Here is how you can achieve that with other means.

First you plot the complete function using the `unknown` terminal. This determines the y-range which would have been used for the complete function. The values are stored in the variables `GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `GPVAL_Y_MAX`. Now you can replot the function using these values as constraints:

```
set terminal unknown
f(x) = sin(x)
set xrange [0:10]
plot f(x)

set terminal pngcairo size 600,300 lw 2
unset key
set output 'test.png'
set samples 1000
graph_y = GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN
y0 = GPVAL_Y_MIN
set yrange[y0 : y0 + graph_y]
plot (y = f(x), (y < y0 + 0.7*graph_y || y > y0 + 0.8*graph_y) ? 1/0 : y)
```

[image]

Comment: this is very interesting... What if instead of a plot it was a splot?

Comment: @Larara You can also use the special file, in this case `"++"` with `splot`. Now instead of only `$1` for x you use also `$2` for y. Just remember to set both `xrange` and `yrange`.